# String not formed when trying to create inside a foreach

Tags: c#, string, oracle, arraylist, parameter-passing

I have a class People_val. I make a list of this class in another class. Now I do a foreach on this list and for each item I call its ToSQL() func which gives me an insert Query. The list count is more than 50,000 records. The 9774 th query is not fully formed.
**9771 INSERT INTO CONVERSION_PEOPLE_VALIDATION VALUES (16413,'Jnto','Johnson',** And because of this the command is not executed and transaction is rolled back.
What should i do inorder to get the full string in foreach.

```
public class People_Val
{
    public int MEMBERS_ID;
    public string PFirstName;
    public string PLastName;

    public DateTime? BIRTH_DATE;
    public string RELATIONSHP;

    public string ToSQL()
    {            
        return string.Format("INSERT INTO CONVERSION_PEOPLE_VALIDATION VALUES ({0},'{1}','{2}','{3}', TO_CHAR('{4}', 'DD-MON-YYYY'))",
                             MEMBERS_ID, PFirstName.Replace("'","\""), PLastName.Replace("'","\""), RELATIONSHP, BIRTH_DATE);
    }
}

public void insertPeopleValTrans(List<People_Val> _lstPeoplevals)
{
    int count=0;
    TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\PeopleVal.txt");
    using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connectionStr)) {
        conn.Open();
        OracleTransaction trans;
        trans = conn.BeginTransaction();
        try {
            foreach (People_Val peopleVal in _lstPeoplevals) {
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(peopleVal.ToSQL(), conn, trans);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                count++;
                if (count % 500 == 0) {
                    Console.WriteLine("saving " + count.ToString() + " Records");
                }
                tw.WriteLine(count.ToString()+" "+ peopleVal.ToSQL());
            }
            trans.Commit();
            tw.Close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            trans.Rollback();
        }
        conn.Close();
    }          
}
```

Comment: have you considered using an ORM instead of this?

Comment: at least, using `OracleCommand` with parameters?

Comment: What is the value of RELATIONSHP for that 9771th People_Val?

Comment: Why is this tagged arraylist?

Comment: In SQL you would escape a single quote in a string with two single quotes: `name.Replace("'","''")`. But I suggest you to use parametrized commands, as DD59 says.

Answer (score 3):

You probably have an apostrophe in some data which is causing your query to fall over.

Try parametrizing your input... it looks like the RELATIONSHIP field is raw data and that may be where the problem is. Have a look at http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/articles/parameters.html I'm fairly sure this will sort you out.

Paste in line 9771 let us see it...

Comment: Relationship at that position is null;

Answer (score 0):

Is it really necessary that all 50000 records either succeed or fail together? Otherwise skip the transaction or at least commit a little more often, maybe something like...

```
if (count % 500 == 0)
{
    trans.Commit();
    Console.WriteLine("saving " + count.ToString() + " Records");
    trans = conn.BeginTransaction();
}
```

And I agree with the previos comments, this would be a minimal effort using Entity Framework Code First.